# Datetime.tryparse with no year value

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to use datetime.tryparse  but when passing "10.2" it succeeds and fills the current year. I wish it to succeed only when passing 10.31.12 or 31.10.12 Etc.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You mean you want it to succeed only when it matches an *exact* format? Then use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) :) Note that it's a bad idea to allow both "10.31.12" and "31.10.12" - otherwise what would "03.04.12" mean, for example? Where is your data coming from - a user, or another system? If it's another system, you should probably use the invariant culture and a custom format string. If it's from a user, it's harder... you should match their culture, and then work out some subset of formats to use.